# Entity Framework + SqlQuery<T>. Don't got collection

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have some entity, but i can't to get some collection from ids. Why not ?

```
public IQueryable<Entity> FindByIds(params int[] ids)
{
    List<Entity> resultList = new List<Entity>();      
    return db.Database.SqlQuery<Entity>("SELECT ID, NAME FROM ENTITY WHERE ID in (:ids)", string.Join(", ",ids));    
}
```

Using model

```
[DataContract]
    public class Entity
    {
        [DataMember]
        public virtual long Id { get; set; }


        [DataMember]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the properties of `Entity`. Those properties must match EXACTLY how the sql returns them or else it won't be able to bind.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using Linq to retrieve data from your DB while using EF?

Comment: I do not use the LINQ because there is a very large nested query and the use of such structures as HAVING, CASE and WITH.

Comment: Which makes sense. LINQ can handle 80% of the queries - sometimes more - but there are edge cases where you need control over the SQL. I have some myself using Pivot or making complex mathematical projections. Good mixure of technologies. Check the properties for an exact match.

Comment: U'r right. But in my situation i have very big and very "crazy" query. In other code I use linq and thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what it was.
Compare 2 string:

Work

```
return db.Database.SqlQuery<Entity>("SELECT ID, NAME FROM ENTITY WHERE ID in (:ids)", string.Join(", ",ids));
```

Does **not** work

```
return db.Database.SqlQuery<Entity>("SELECT ID, NAME FROM ENTITY WHERE ID in (:ids)", string.Join(",",ids));
```

Oracle not understand ", " in code